# How to make it such that the UI initially shows a text box but when i click on it, a calendar widget pops up?

Tags: flutter, dart

`This is my widget that i want to pop up.`

```
CustomCalendar(
                          earliestDate: DateTime.now()
                              .subtract(const Duration(days: 120 * 365)),
                          latestDate: DateTime.now()
                              .subtract(const Duration(days: 18 * 365)),
                          validationCallBack: (text) {
                          BlocProvider.of<
                                  FormValidationBloc<
                                      KnowMoreValidationResult>>(context)
                              .add(FieldUpdatedEvent(
                                  fieldName: formDefinition.dobField,
                                  value: text!.toIso8601String()));
                          return null;
                        }),
```

I cant seem to find a way to toggle the widget. I want the UI to initially show a textfield widget but when pressed, to pop up the above widget, has anyone implemented something like this before.

Comment: Use [showDialog](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showDialog.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
 showDialog(
    context: context,
    barrierDismissible: false,
    builder: (context) => CustomCalendar(),
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can make a clickable text which you can create by wrapping that particular text inside the onTap widget of flutter and then you can popup the CustomCalendar widget

Comment: Your answer is not clear enough. Add a code snippet to demonstrate your explanation.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).